# Can Azure AKS operate on Managed Identities without requiring a Contributor role?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-managed-identity, azure-rbac

Our enterprise strictly disallows the use of `Contributor` and a handful of other extremely-powerful RBAC roles in Azure.

When I deploy AKS and pre-configure it to use two managed identities, which have been granted all RBAC actions documented per the [AKS Service Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-identity#aks-service-permissions), the service **still** attempts to assign itself `Contributor`.

Can Azure Kubernetes Service function without `Contributor`, or is `Contributor` an undocumented and absolute requirement?

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 of the managed indentities that have contributor rights by default:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity

These roles manage the cluster, as such they need contributor rights.

Comment: interesting -- the control plane and kubelet mention "Bring your own identity", and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-identity#identity-creating-and-operating-the-cluster-permissions lists specific RBAC actions.  In practice we're finding it still self-escalates one of those identities to Contributor